# Child Div not showing border

Tags: css, html, border

I have a webpage with two nested divs.

I need the inside div to show its border, however it is not. I have tryed every suggestion I have come across, but no avail.

while trying different solutions, I have noticed that the parent div does show its border without much hassle. What am I doing wrong?

css

```
.contentItemsWrapper
{   
    margin:auto;

    width: 900px ;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;

    text-align:center;

    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;

    border:solid red;
        border-width:5px 0;
/*this div's border is showing up fine.*/   
}




.contentEventItem {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;


    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative;

    border:solid red;
        border-width:5px 0;

/* this last one is not working*/
}
```

HTLM:

```
<div class="contentItemsWrapper">                
              <div class="contentEventItem style=" border:solid="" red;="" border-width:5px="" 0;="" "="" id="evento1">            
                <div class="DataIncontro" id="dataIncontro1">
                    <span class="month">Decembre</span>
                    <span class="number">26</span>
                    <span class="time">15:00</span>
                    <span class="day">Gio</span>
                </div>

                <div class="logoSquadra"><span class="helper"></span><img name="" src="images/logo_nbb.png" alt="" style="background-color: #003399"></div>

                <div class="nameEventLocation" id="nameEventLocation1">
                    <strong class="eventname">New Basket Brindisi - Cremonese</strong>
                    <span class="location">Nome Stadio</span>
                </div>

                <div class="logoSquadra"><img name="" src="images/logo_nbb.png" alt="" style="background-color: #003399"></div>


                <div class="noteEvento">Aquistabili online fino al xx dicemnre, ore 20.00</div>


                <div class="buttonDiv">
                  <p>
                    <a class="multi-line-button green" href="#" style="width:14em">
                      <span class="title">Compra Ora!</span>
                      <span class="subtitle">30-days free!</span>
                    </a>
                  </p> 
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Can somebody please help me?

Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Im confused, you want this?

### CSS:

```
.contentEventItem {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    /* this last one is now working*/
}
```

All I have done is add `border: 1px solid #000;` and deleted this odd HTML:

```
border:solid="" red;="" border-width:5px="" 0;="" "=""
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N5CDv/)

Comment: yes exactly. Strangely it's not working. I had already tried that without success. I gave it another go, but without any success. I have tried commenting out the HTML inside in case some inside element is causing the problem, but I had no luck. What else can I check?

Comment: Then its something else because you can see that works.  Do you have a link to the page or maybe put the full page somewhere I can see it?

Comment: Ok I have updated the whole page online. I home you trust me. I am behind a proxy allowing only web traffic. So I am unable to upload the page to on a web server through ftp. I hope you trust the link, if not please let me know how would you like me to send the page. http://www.sendspace.com/file/6no8gh Thank you very much in advance for your time. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 border-width:5px 0;
```

There is no shorthand for more than one border position. Try this instead.

```
border-bottom: 5px solid red;
border-top: 5px solid red;
border-left:none;
border-right:none;
```